# The Alternates For 'in respect of' In Two Cases

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

I'd like to ask if the three phrases below can be used instead of ***in respect of*** in the two cases and still mean the same thing.

1. *with respect to*
2. *in/with regard to*
3. *as regards*

- *A writ was served on the firm **in respect of** their unpaid bill.*
- *money received **in respect** of overtime worked*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They all sound unnecessarily fancy and wordy and would not be considered good writing style,  in my opinion.  Better to just use "for" or "regarding" instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answering.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, first I'd like to confirm the answer to the question I intended. Can the three other phrases be used instead in the two expressions? To me, it feels that #1, #3 sound a bit weird.

I am sorry but really have to check this.

And for one of your suggestions, doesn't the phrase ***money received regarding overtime worked*** sound weird?